# SubNav Not Appearing

Tags: html, css

Please see below for my coding. I am struggling to get my SubNav to appear when you hover over "Shop". I copied parts of code below from other projects that work, but now nothing is happening. For the SubNav, I am just looking for the menu to drop down and show the other items. This will go on all pages of the site. Any suggestions? Thanks!

```css
/* stlyes for body */

body {
  font-family: 'Trocchi', serif;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 3px solid #FEFA91;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

a {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
}

a:link,
a:visited {
  color: black;
}

a:hover,
a:focus {
  color: #FEFA91;
}


/* Header */

header {
  background-color: #FEFA91;
  width: 100%;
}

header img {
  display: block;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  padding-top: 5px;
}


/* the styles for the navigation menu */

#nav_menu {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#nav_menu ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}

#nav_menu ul li {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
}

#nav_menu ul li a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1em 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #FEFA91;
  color: black;
}

#nav_menu a.current {
  color: white;
}

#nav_menu ul ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
}

#nav_menu ul ul li {
  float: none;
}

#nav_menu ul li a:hover,
#nav_menu ul li a:focus {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

#nav_menu ul li:hover>ul {
  display: block;
}

#nav_menu>ul:after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: block;
}


/* Main */

main {
  padding: 20px;
  max-width: 950px;
  height: auto;
}


/* Section */

section {
  width: 660px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 11px 0 0 0;
}

section img {
  padding: 0 15px 10px 15px;
}

section p {
  text-align: left;
  margin: 10px;
}

section dl {
  font-size: 13px;
  text-indent: 30px;
  padding: 20px 0 0 0;
}

section h1 {
  font-size: 35px;
  font-family: 'Euphoria Script', cursive;
}


/* Aside 1 */

#aside1 {
  width: 150px;
  height: 310px;
  float: left;
  background-color: #FEFA91;
  padding: 10px 0 0 0;
  text-align: center;
}

#aside1 img {
  text-align: center;
}


/* Aside 2 */

#aside2 {
  width: 150px;
  height: 310px;
  float: right;
  background-color: #FEFA91;
  padding: 10px 0 0 0;
  text-align: center;
}

#aside2 img {
  text-align: center;
}

#aside2 h2 {
  font-size: 15px;
}

#aside2 p {
  font-size: 13px;
}

#aside2 hr {
  border: 1px #000000 solid;
}


/* Footer */

footer {
  clear: both;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: #FEFA91;
  position: relative;
}

footer p {
  font-size: 90%;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Ears To You Boutique - Holiday Ears</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../images/tansp.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/ears.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Euphoria+Script">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Trocchi">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <a href="../index.html"><img src="../images/rsz_logo.png" alt="Logo" height="100" class="center"></a>
  </header>
  <nav id="nav_menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="../pages/about.html">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="../pages/shop.html">Shop</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="../pages/holidayears.html">Holiday</a></li>
          <li><a href="../pages/characterears.html">Character</a></li>
          <li><a href="../pages/eventears.html">Event</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="../pages/gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
      <li><a href="../pages/calendar.html">Calendar</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <main>
    <aside id="aside1">
      <img src="../images/castle.jpg" width="125px">
      <img src="../images/christmas2.jpg" width="125px">
      <img src="../images/christmas3.jpg" width="125px">
    </aside>
    <section>
      <img src="../images/christmas1.jpg" width="220px" style="float:left">
      <h1>Christmas Ears</h1>
      <p>Do you love Christmas?
        <br />If so, these red and green ears featuring ice skating elves are perfect for you!</p>
      <p>Purchase at <a href="http://www.etsy.com" target="_blank">Etsy.com</a></p>
      <dl>
        <dt>Bow: Red</dt>
        <dt>Band: Green</dt>
        <dt>Ears: Red & Green with Elves</dt>
      </dl>
    </section>
    <aside id="aside2">
      <h2>Shop Other <br />Holiday Ears</h2>
      <hr>
      <br />
      <img src="../images/halloween.jpg" width="125px">
      <p>Halloween</p>
      <br />
      <br />
      <img src="../images/spring.jpg" width="125px">
      <p>Spring</p>
    </aside>
  </main>
  <footer>
    <p>
      <a href="http://www.facebook.com" target="blank"><img src="../images/face.png" width="40"></a>
      <a href="http://www.instagram.com" target="blank"><img src="../images/insta.jpg" width="36"></a>
      <a href="http://www.pinterest.com" target="blank"><img src="../images/pin.jpg" width="40"></a>
    </p>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#nav_menu {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden; //remove
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#nav_menu ul ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  width: 100%; // added
}
```

Comment: Hamza, thank you! You are a lifesaver! Do you know how I might fix the Aside 2? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I added `flexbox` property on the section, Flexbox aligns `left` `main` and `right` column at the same row. There is good instruction about [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) btw.

```
section {
  display:flex; // Add flex
  width: 660px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 11px 0 0 0;
}
```

Comment: Code only answers can generally be improved by adding some explanatory text to them.

Comment: I added as a quick solution. Just updated answer thanks for the notice @JasonAller